# Pundit don't see user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am a newbie when it comes to RubyOnRails. Recently while working with the gem pundit I encountered a problem. Pundit during function `sort?` authorization does not see the logged in user that is `@user = nill`. I don't know what the problem is because other authorizations with the same syntax works for example `edit?` I am uploading the code below:

lesson_controler.rb

```
 class LessonsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_lesson, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
      
      def sort
        @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
        @lesson = Lesson.friendly.find(params[:lesson_id])
        authorize @lesson
        @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        render body: nil
      end
      
      def index
        @lessons = Lesson.all
      end
    
      def show
        authorize @lesson
        current_user.view_lesson(@lesson)
        @lessons = @course.lessons
      end
    
      def new
        @lesson = Lesson.new
        @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
      end
    
      def edit
        authorize @lesson
      end
      
      def create
        @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
        @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
        @lesson.course_id = @course.id
        authorize @lesson
        respond_to do |format|
          if @lesson.save
            format.html { redirect_to course_lesson_path(@course,@lesson), notice: "Lesson was successfully created." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lesson }
          else
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      def update
        authorize @lesson
        respond_to do |format|
          if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
            format.html { redirect_to course_lesson_path(@course,@lesson), notice: "Lesson was successfully updated." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @lesson }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      def destroy
        authorize @lesson
        @lesson.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to course_path(@course), notice: "Lesson was successfully destroyed." }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    
      private
        def set_lesson
          @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
          @lesson = Lesson.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
    
        def lesson_params
          params.require(:lesson).permit(:title, :content, :row_order_position)
        end
    end
```

lesson_policy.rb:

```
class LessonPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end
  
  def sort?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end  
  
  def edit?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end
  
  def update?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end
  
  def destroy?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end
  
  def show?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id || @user&.has_role?(:admin) || @record.course.bought(@user) == false
  end 
  
  def new?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end 
  
  def create?
    @record.course.user_id == @user.id
  end  
  
end
```

Application_policy.rb:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  class Scope
    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.all
    end

    private

    attr_reader :user, :scope
  end
end
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiEd4.png)

How can I make a logged in user visible to pundit?

Comment: Are you actually authenticating the user?

Comment: Yes, before any action user must be logged in so current_user exist.